# Calculated field formula IF statement between two values

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this?

```
=IF( [Hourly rate]>160
     ,4
     ,IF( AND[Hourly rate > 145,[Hourly rate] <160,3
        )
          ,IF( [Hourly rate]=145
               ,2
               ,IF( [Hourly rate]<145 
                    ,1
                  )
             )
   )
```

I just want to say

If rate > 160 show 4, else if rate > 145 AND < 160 show 3, else if rate < 145 show 1.

Comment: Is it giving you a syntax error or is it failing to show the correct value, that will help answerers to know what is wrong.

Comment: I only added linebreaks... always built your Formula in Notepad or any Texteditor... Easy to spot your problem then

Comment: It was throwing a syntax error.  Sorry yes I could have been more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing your syntax:

```
=IF( [Hourly rate]>160
     ,4
     ,IF( AND( [Hourly rate] >145 , [Hourly rate] <160 )
          ,3
          ,IF( [Hourly rate]=145
               ,2
               ,IF( [Hourly rate]<145 
                    ,1
                  )
             )
   )
```

#### Better:

```
=IF( [Hourly rate]<145
     ,1
     ,IF( [Hourly rate]=145
               ,2
               ,IF( [Hourly rate]<160 
                    ,3
                    ,4
                  )
       )
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below formula. It will work as per your need (Explained in question).

```
=IF([Hourly rate]>160,4,IF(AND([Hourly rate] > 145,[Hourly rate] <160),3,IF([Hourly rate]=145,2,IF([Hourly rate]<145,1))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I this worked perfectly, but I have given the marked answer to suggestive improvements.

Comment: BTW I gave simple solution ... I thought you are able to use it directly.